# Should I make a new PHP file for this code?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, file-structure

I am customizing an already existing theme. The theme uses a header.php and a footer.php. I noticed that the `<body>` and `</body>` tags are split between the two PHP files, respectively. If I want to make a `<form>` element that will *not* be a part of the navbar at the top nor the footer links at the bottom, should I make a separate PHP file? This might seem like common sense for most, but I am very new to web dev. I'm asking because it is also possible to put it *under* the navbar code in my header.php file.

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1" />
    <title><?php wp_title( ' | ', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">
        <header id="header" role="banner">
            <section id="branding">

            </section>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.efficientmind.org/?page_id=73&ap_page=ask">MoonLighting</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="http://www.efficientmind.org/?page_id=73">Side Job</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">My Account <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Add Funds</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

**footer.php**

```
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">
<div id="copyright">
<?php echo sprintf( __( '%1$s %2$s %3$s. All Rights Reserved.', 'blankslate' ), '&copy;', date( 'Y' ), esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) ); echo sprintf( __( ' Theme By: %1$s.', 'blankslate' ), '<a href="http://tidythemes.com/">TidyThemes</a>' ); ?>
</div>
</footer>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you should make it separate.

Comment: @JayBlanchard ok, thanks for confirming. Which `get` function should I use to reference that php file?

Comment: You should be able to us `include()` safely.

Comment: @whatintarnation it really depends on if your going to be using the form on another page or not, if the form is specific to only this page you could just put it the same file where your including header.php, footer.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is that code which will be reused among multiple pages should be split off into a separate file, like `header.php` and `footer.php`. This makes a project easier to maintain. Furthermore each file should try to only accomplish one task.

Basically if not all uses of the header file will need this form, it should go into a separate file.

Comment: @whatintarnation exactly what I'm saying in my post above if your going to be using the form on more then one page then create a "template" file just for the form and include it like you are doing for the header/footer...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two things here:

1. The form will be on top of *every* page
2. There will be no identical form somewhere else (ie. in the contents or footer of the page)

It would definately belong in the header.
if it is a common form that you would use somewhere else (like a login form would maybe be used on top of every page *and* on a login page) you should add it as a function in a templates.php file, and call that function from the header.